# how to know event.pageX and event.pageY is increasing or decreasing in jQuery-Ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using this following jQuery-UI code in my programming, can anybody know how to know, whether event.pageX and event.pageY is increasing or decreasing while resizing a particular div.

CODE:

```
fontSize = parseInt($(' span',this).css('fontSize'));
$(this).resizable({
               disabled:false,
               handles: 'nw, ne, se, sw',
               resize: function(event, ui) { 
                         xvalue = event.pageX;
                         yvalue = event.pageY;
                         fontSize = fontSize+.1;
                         $(" span",this).css("fontSize",fontSize);
                       }
});
```

can anybody how to get to know is that xvalue and yvalue is increasing or decreasing ??

Answer (score 1):

```
var fontSize = parseInt($('span', this).css('fontSize'));
var xValue, yValue;

var f = function(event, ui) {
   var isXIncreasing = xXalue < event.pageX;
   var isYIncreasing = yValue < event.pageY;
   // ^ you can do something with these now

   xValue = event.pageX;
   yValue = event.pageY;
   fontSize = fontSize+.1;
   $('span', this).css("fontSize",fontSize);
};

$(this).resizable({
    disabled: false,
    handles:  'nw, ne, se, sw',
    resize:   f
});
```

Comment: how to compare, its always get equal ??

Comment: @Srikanth: Perform comparison with the `<` and `>` operators.

Comment: nice one @Tomalak Geret'kal, but if i am dragging using top-right corner to down xvalue is increasing, so font is increasing, but it should decrease. Thank you.

Comment: @Srikanth: `x` does not increase as you drag down. Up/down is `y`.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare `ui.originalSize` and `ui.size` to see whether the current resizing operation is decreasing or increasing the size.

For instance:

```
resize: function(event, ui) { 
    if (ui.size.height > ui.originalSize.height) {
        // element is taller than before
    } else {
        // element is the same size or smaller than before
    }
}
```

By analogy, you can use `ui.size.width` and `ui.originalSize.width` to see if the element is wider than before.

[See the API](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#overview).

Comment: ui.size.height > ui.size.originalHeight is not working, always its going to else statements.

Comment: @Srikanth Sorry, typo -- should have been `ui.originalSize.height`. NB that `originalSize` is from before the original operation, rather than from the last `resize` call.

Comment: thank you, i saw that, see its raising another bug to me, if am increasing the element size and again decreasing the size of element without releasing the mouse button, the font is still increasing, actually it should decrease while reducing the height of the div.

Comment: @Srikanth That's because it's larger than `originalSize`, which is the size of the element before the resize action occured. If I were you, I'd bind to the `stop` event instead and only change the font size after the resizing was over. Your system could easily cause a lot of lag in older browsers.